# Relative paths in listings using Quarto

Tags: quarto

I'm having issues using relative paths when trying to create a listing on a html page with Quarto. The file structure is as follows:

```
_quarto.yml
dir1/index.qmd
dir2/test.qmd
```

The content of `_quarto.yml`:

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Test"
  sidebar:
    contents:
      - href: dir1/index.qmd
        text: Index

format: html
```

The content of `dir1/index.qmd`:

```
---
title: "Title"
listing:
  - id: test
    contents:
      - ../dir2/test.qmd
    type: table
    fields: [title]
    field-display-names:
      title: "Title"
---

## Section
```

The content of `dir2/test.qmd`:

```
---
title: "Slides"
format: revealjs
---

# Welcome!
```

When compiling this gives me an empty listing/table. If I put `test.qmd` anywhere else without having to "go up" a directory, then it works. Am I using `../` incorrectly?

Comment: I have tried your example in VS Code / quarto 1.3.353 and it worked out of the box. 
I rendered index.qmd. Mærkeligt.

Comment: @Ute: Thanks for the reply! I forgot to mention that I'm on 1.4.92, so I'll try to downgrade and see if the issue persists or not.

Comment: Indeed it was a bug with the pre-release version. I've submitted a bug request to their GitHub page.

Comment: No need to downgrade to 1.3.353 (official release) - it works there :-)

Comment: Was fixed in the newest pre-release (1.4.117).